# Why did this happen to King Fred?

Tags: the-ickabog

In [*Cornucopia Again*, Chapter 64](https://www.theickabog.com/cornucopia-again/) of The Ickabog,

> Spittleworth and King Fred are imprisoned for life.

This is proved by

> Both men were imprisoned in the dungeons beneath the palace, with all the other criminals.
>  [...]
>  All this time, Fred had been crying his eyes out down in the dungeons. Selfish, vain, and cowardly though he'd definitely been, Fred hadn't meant to hurt anyone - though of course he had, and very badly too.
>  [...]
>  Fred told the prison guard that he'd like to volunteer to be the one to look after the savage Ickabog.
>  [...]
>  Slowly, over the months and years that followed, Fred became braver and the Ickabog gentler, and at last, when Fred was quite an old man, the Ickabog’s Bornding came, and the Ickaboggles that stepped out of it were kind and gentle. Fred, who’d mourned their Icker as though it had been his brother, died very shortly afterwards.

[*Cornucopia Again*, Chapter 64](https://www.theickabog.com/cornucopia-again/)

This seems very strange, since as far as I can tell, he lacked [*mens rea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_rea) - the intention to do any of it at all. I think his only culpability would be due to negligence, which Spittleworth and Flapoon conspired to create.

As Mrs Beamish says in [Chapter 41](https://www.theickabog.com/mrs-beamishs-plan/),

> ‘The king can’t know,’ she whispered. ‘He can’t. He’s a good man.’

The precedent was unreasonable punishments while Spittleworth was the *de facto* ruler, but Captain Goodfellow is supposed to be a good fellow (heh). He is described as fair, which makes this particular case seem unusual.

In fact in [*The Trial*, Chapter 23](https://www.theickabog.com/the-trial/), Goodfellow is unfairly imprisoned himself.

Why does King Fred...

> ...get a life sentence?

Comment: I noticed this too.

Comment: I noticed this too.

Comment: Sounds really unfair