# Who judged Lord Spittleworth's hearing?

Tags: the-ickabog

Lord Spittleworth had to attend a hearing after he was arrested by Bert and Roderick. But who could have judged the case? It couldn't have been King Fred because he was arrested as well. Who are the possible candidates?

Comment: I assume Gordon Goodfellow?

Comment: Lady Eslanda  ? She's the one who says that there will be a hearing

Comment: The 11 advisors  ?

Comment: Whoever it was, [they weren't very fair](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234309/why-did-this-happen-to-king-fred).